# Does sendgrid provide response code for each email when send multiple in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sendgrid

I am using Sendgrid for sending multiple email. After sending the email I need to get all the responses of the  each email. But I getting single 202 to code from sendGrid. Is there any other method.

```
var sendGridMessage = new SendGridMessage();
        sendGridMessage.SetFrom(message.From.Email, message.From.Name);
        sendGridMessage.SetSubject(message.Subject);
        sendGridMessage.Contents = new List<Content>(){
            new Content() {
                Type = "text/html",
                Value = message.Body
            }
        };
        if (message.To != null)
        {
            foreach (var toAddress in message.To)
            {
                sendGridMessage.AddTo(toAddress.Email, toAddress.Name);
            }
        }
        if (message.Cc != null)
        {
            foreach (var ccAddress in message.Cc)
            {
                sendGridMessage.AddCc(ccAddress.Email, ccAddress.Name);
            }
        }
        if (message.Bcc != null)
        {
            foreach (var bccAddress in message.Bcc)
            {
                sendGridMessage.AddBcc(bccAddress.Email, bccAddress.Name);
            }
        }
        if (message.ReplyTo != null)
        {
            foreach (var replyToAddress in message.ReplyTo)
            {
                sendGridMessage.AddReplyTo(replyToAddress.Email, replyToAddress.Name);
            }
        }
        sendGridMessage.AddHeader("Importance", Enum.GetName(typeof(EmailImportance), message.Importance));
         var sendGridResponse = await _sendGridClient.SendEmailAsync(sendGridMessage);
```

Here I am looping the To address using addTo method. This sendEmailAsync response is a single statuscode. I need status code for each To address